# Robot Framework dropdown and libraries

Tags: python, libraries, robotframework

So i want to create libraries in the PyCharm and then put these libraries in Robot Framework IDE, RIDE. My Library inherit the Selenium2Library. So i have two questions, can i inherit in my custom library another ready library like WebDriver? Also i cant find way to select a value from a dropdown with Selenium2Library, anyone know a way?

```html
<ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Α</li>
  <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Β</li>
  <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Γ</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, yes you can inherit webdriver class that is part of Selenium2Library python library. Basically you can inherit any python class.

What do you mean by "select a value from a dropdown"?
Do you want to click the item of the dropdown or retrieve the name (caption) of a item in the dropdown?